# Compiler discrepancy for out-of-line definitions of conversion operators

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

There appears to be some discrepancy between compilers as to whether the following code is well formed.
In particular, GCC and Clang accept this code -- whereas MSVC rejects it:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Bar{};

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    using element_type = T;

    operator Bar<element_type>();
};

template <typename T>
Foo<T>::operator Bar<element_type>()
{
    return {};
}
```

MSVC's rejection message is just a generic:

> `<source>(11): error C2065: 'element_type': undeclared identifier`

The issue only appears to occur when the template argument for the conversion type is a dependent template type, since this is resolved by changing `Bar<element_type>` to either `Bar<T>` or `Bar<typename Foo<T>::element_type>`. I've made a small example on [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/RKuYtr) to demonstrate this. This appears to occur from C++11 (possibly older, didn't test) up to C++2a, and is independent of the compiler's versions or flags.

I know that C++ allows dropping the prefixing class-name specifier for types when in the body or parameter list of a class function/constructor definition -- but I'm unsure whether this same short-form is allowed when handling a conversion operator in an out-of-line definition.

**Is this an ambiguity in the standard, or a bug in either of the compilers?** I'm mostly curious to know how this is defined (or not, as it may be) in the C++ standard.

---

**Edit:** To add to the confusion, it appears that MSVC *accepts* the following code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    using element_type = T;
    operator element_type();
};

template <typename T>
Foo<T>::operator element_type() // note: no 'typename' syntax
{
    return {};
}
```

so this doesn't appear to be just an issue caused from conversion to template-dependent type names... I'm suspecting this may be an MSVC bug rather than a discrepancy.

Comment: What compiler versions? What compilation options? What C++ language version?

Comment: Independent of compiler versions, independent of compiler options, and I already stated independent of language version. Though my example is technically C++11 at least, due to my `using` syntax. Updated the footnote to emphasize this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard is very vague on the subject.  In the case where you're explicitly *calling* a conversion function (`a.operator int()`), [basic.lookup.classref]/7 says

> If the *id-expression* is a *conversion-function-id*, its *conversion-type-id* is first looked up in the class of the object expression ([class.member.lookup]) and the name, if found, is used.

Unfortunately, a *conversion-type-id* can have [any number of **names**](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2396.html) (including 0), in which case it is impossible to look up directly.  [class.qual]/1.2 applies the same non-rule to references to the function using `::`, which may or may not apply to out-of-class definitions of such functions (since normal lookup doesn't apply there).

There is massive implementation divergence.  In the following example, the comments indicate which compilers (the most current versions at the moment on Compiler Explorer) reject which lines (usually because they can't find the name):

```
struct X {
  struct A {};
  operator A();

  template<class> struct B {};
  using C = int;
  operator B<C>();

  struct D {using I=int; I i;};
  operator int D::*();
  operator D::I();

  static float E;
  operator decltype(E)();

  struct G {};
  operator struct G();
};

X::operator A() {throw;}            // OK
X::operator B<C>() {throw;}         // MSVC: B and C
X::operator int D::*() {throw;}     // MSVC
X::operator D::I() {throw;}         // MSVC
X::operator decltype(E)() {throw;}  // MSVC
X::operator struct G() {throw;}     // MSVC thinks G is ::G

void f(X x) {
  x.operator A();            // Clang, MSVC
  x.operator B<C>();         // GCC, Clang, ICC: C; MSVC: B and C
  x.operator int D::*();     // Clang
  x.operator D::I();         // Clang
  x.operator decltype(E)();  // Clang, ICC, MSVC; GCC segfaults
  x.operator struct G();     // GCC, Clang, MSVC think G is local to f
}
```

Clang accepts all the definitions and rejects all the calls because it doesn't implement [basic.lookup.classref]/7 at all but helpfully misapplies [basic.scope.class]/4 *within* the *declarator-id* when it is a *conversion-function-id*.

[New rules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html) have been applied (retroactively) to clarify this mess (along with many other messes).  The explicit calls involving `A`, `B`, `D`, and `G` are now valid.

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was hoping for. Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing for optimal portability, cross-platform code should likely avoid this issue altogether by defining conversion operators in-line rather than out-of-line. Would you happen to know if these new rules will be applied as a defect to older versions of C++ as well?

Comment: @Human-Compiler: It’s also possible to avoid the issue by using type(def) names that have the same meaning whether or not they are looked up in the class.  I don’t know yet what the intent is for retroactive changes in implementations (which is more important than official DR status).

Comment: In order to extend the confusion here, try to add operator auto() to the example... ;)